# Room runInTransaction for multiple DAO

Tags: java, android, android-room

How to use Room runInTransaction, 
I have multiple table to insert.

```
database.runInTransaction(() -> {
                        database.getMemberDAO().insert(response.body().getMembers());
                        database.getPostDAO().insert(response.body().getPosts());
                        database.getCommentDAO().insert(response.body().getComments());
                        database.getLikeDAO().insert(response.body().getLikes());
                        database.getPostImageDAO().insert(response.body().getPostImages());
                    });
```

I'm getting foreign key constraint error when running this transaction.
Running line by line works. but bulk insert not working for multiple table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed using try-catch-finally

```
database.runInTransaction(() -> {
                        try {
                            database.getMemberDAO().insert(response.body().getMembers());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                database.getPostDAO().insert(response.body().getPosts());
                            } catch (Exception e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                try {
                                    database.getCommentDAO().insert(response.body().getComments());
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } finally {
                                    try {
                                        database.getLikeDAO().insert(response.body().getLikes());
                                    } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    } finally {
                                        try {
                                            database.getPostImageDAO().insert(response.body().getPostImages());
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        } finally {
                                            database.endTransaction();

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    });
```